# Double ToString gives rounded result

Tags: c#, double, precision

Why does this simple Console App Output `100000000000000` instead of `99999999999999.99` or atleast `99999999999999.984` as the debugger is showing?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double bigNum = 99999999999999.99;
    Console.WriteLine(bigNum); //Console.WriteLine will internally ToString, but you can add what ever ToString() you want here the result will always be undesired
}
```

Console Output:

[image: Nope]

Debug Output:

[image]

For clarification:

Yes, I know of the value type `decimal` and its superiour precision over `double`, but I never heard of that `ToString()` of `double` could give wrong results.

Comment: define  "wrong", it has an accuracy of 0.00000000000001% ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `double` has limited precision, so it will only store the first 15-16 digits of your number. For more precision, use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` - it doesn't support non-integers though, so you must add the decimal points yourself (if you have a fixed number of decimals).

Comment: Try using `bigNum.ToString("R")` or `Console.WriteLine("{0:R}", bigNum);`

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think the question is different - "why debugger does not match `double.ToString("G")`" rather than generic explanation of double's behavior. (Note that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString tells you to use `"G17"` if you want to keep all digits, by default `"G"` is `"G15"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the standard `ToString` conversion:

> If format is null or an empty string, the return value is formatted with the general numeric format specifier ("G").

This will show you, that the defaulted number format specifier "G", will default to max 15 digits if possible: [G-format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString)

As requested:

```
double bigNum = 99999999999999.99;

Console.WriteLine(bigNum);                 //default
//100000000000000
Console.WriteLine(bigNum.ToString("G"));   //explicit default
//100000000000000
Console.WriteLine(bigNum.ToString("G17")); //G17
//99999999999999.984
```

Comment: Thx, do you know how I could do this with the thousands seperator in use? So, how to fix my issue with `.ToString("N2")` ? Dont think I can combine G and N ?!?

Comment: You can try: `Console.WriteLine(bigNum.ToString("G17"));` I'll run a test to see if it works.

Comment: Nope, this results in the correct value (as the debugger) but without the thousand seperators.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you meant the decimal sepperator.

Comment: I'll need to check that, one moment

Comment: No problem, take your time.

Comment: Sorry, no luck. I tried a custom `NumberInfoFormat` and some `###.###...etc` styles but they all tend to round the number to 1000000..

Comment: To bad :( - seems like I have to do my own stuff - gona try "G17" and than add the thousand seperator.